# Trying to understand the inheritance chain

Tags: c#, inheritance, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, access-specifier

Below is Parent & Child class.

```
public class ParentController : ApiController
{
   public ICustomer customer { get; set;}
   public ICustUtil util { get; set;}

}


public class ChildController : ParentController
{
    //no issue here
    public string Get()
    {
       customer = util.GetCustomers();
     }

}
```

If I make the parent class properties as protected & try to use them, I get `Object NULL reference Exception`

```
public class ParentController : ApiController
{
   protected ICustomer customer { get; set;}
   protected ICustUtil util { get; set;}

}


public class ChildController : ParentController
{
    //Object Null reference exception at run time here
    public string Get(){
    customer = util.GetCustomers();}

}
```

I am trying to understand how does it make difference updating `public` to `protected` access specifier.

Please note:-

> - I am using `Castle Windsor DI` container

Please ignore naming convention for now.

Comment: @Kgn-web: No, that code really won't compile. You need something like `public class ParentController : ApiController`. Then your `ChildController` code won't compile either, as you have a non-declaration directly in the class declaration. Please provide a [mcve]. (I'd also strongly advise you to learn about .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, My typo mistake. I sincerly apologize for it

Comment: The reason for your exception not-regarding your compiler-errors is probably that you never instantiate your `utils`-property within your `ChildController`-class.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, as I metioned that I am using DI Nulll reference issue arise only when making the members as protected

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have corrected my post,can you please share your thoughts now?? Thanks

Comment: "Please ignore naming convention for now." Why not just *fix it* instead? Stack Overflow is intended to be a repository of high-quality questions and answers - you should put effort into making your question as high quality as posisble. It doesn't help that you haven't shown us *how* you're using Castle Windsor... we still have no way of reproducing the problem. Presumably nothing is setting `ICustUtil` to a non-null value, but we don't know what you've done to try to set that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are instantiating instances of these classes via an IoC container like AutoFac, and you are using setter injection. Otherwise I can't see how the first example would ever work, since you never initialize `util`.

When a member is protected, an IoC container can't initialize it. Only public members can be accessed by code outside the class itself.

Comment: Yes.You guessed correct. I am using Castle Windsor DI container (FYI - I have mentioned in my post)

Comment: Sincere thanks for posting this. I was not knowing this. :)